# assign multi-dimension array to another

Tags: c++, multidimensional-array, assign

i have these structures:

```
struct tcFrameConfig {
    int           NameF; 
    int           NameP;
    int           NameH;
    unsigned __int8 Length;
    unsigned int  Duration; };

struct tcFrameStimulus {
    short Key; };

struct tcFrame {
    tcFrameConfig      Config;
    tcFrameStimulus* Stimulus; };

int main() {
    tcFrame Frame1;
    tcFrame Frame2;

    Frame1.Config.NameF = 0;
    Frame1.Config.NameP = 0;
    Frame1.Config.NameH = 0;
    Frame1.Config.Length = 4;
    Frame1.Config.Duration = 100;

    Frame1.Stimulus = new tcFrameStimulus[Frame1.Config.Length];
    Frame1.Stimulus[0] = 0;
    Frame1.Stimulus[1] = 1;
    Frame1.Stimulus[2] = 40;
    Frame1.Stimulus[3] = 43;
```

ok i initialized `Frame1`;
now... if i do:

```
Frame2 = Frame1;
return 0; }
```

it works, but i dont think its right, what is the proper way?, 
and if `Frame1` was  actually an dynamic array of `tcFrame`?

update....

from

```
struct tcFrame {
    tcFrameConfig      Config;
    tcFrameStimulus* Stimulus; };
```

i went to

```
struct tcFrame {
    tcFrameConfig      Config;
    std::vector<tcFrameStimulus> Stimulus;  };
```

compiler says

```
error: 'struct tcFrame' has no member named 'Stimulus'|
```

had some tests on this code

```
int main() {
tcFrame Frame1;
tcFrame Frame2;

Frame1.Config.NameF = 0;
Frame1.Config.NameH = 0;
Frame1.Config.NameP = 0;
Frame1.Config.Length = 4;
Frame1.Config.Duration = 100;

Frame1.Stimulus = new tcFrameStimulus[Frame1.Config.Length];
Frame1.Stimulus[0].Key = 0;
Frame1.Stimulus[1].Key = 1;
Frame1.Stimulus[2].Key = 2;
Frame1.Stimulus[3].Key = 3;

Frame2 = Frame1;

Frame1.Config.NameF = 1;
Frame1.Config.NameH = 1;
Frame1.Config.NameP = 1;
Frame1.Config.Length = 4;
Frame1.Config.Duration = 200;

Frame1.Stimulus = new tcFrameStimulus[Frame1.Config.Length];
Frame1.Stimulus[0].Key = 1;
Frame1.Stimulus[1].Key = 2;
Frame1.Stimulus[2].Key = 3;
Frame1.Stimulus[3].Key = 4;

cout << Frame1.Config.NameF  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Config.NameH  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Config.NameP  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Config.Length  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Config.Duration  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Stimulus[0].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Stimulus[1].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Stimulus[2].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame1.Stimulus[3].Key  << endl;

cout << Frame2.Config.NameF  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Config.NameH  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Config.NameP  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Config.Length  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Config.Duration  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Stimulus[0].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Stimulus[1].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Stimulus[2].Key  << endl;
cout << Frame2.Stimulus[3].Key  << endl;

return 0; }
```

and the Frames had different values...

Comment: Why don't you think it's right? What do you expect to happen, and what actually happened that you didn't want?

Comment: by simply using the = operator, does it create the Frame2.stimulues array, or it's allocating the values in another adress?

Comment: This is not C code, so the [c] tag is inappropriate.  `main` may not be declared to return `void`; it always has return type `int`.

Comment: sorry, i just quicly typed the code, im a delphi programer and im learning c++ now, my question is, can i assign any array by simply using the = operator?

Comment: I don't see any multidimensional arrays in this code

Comment: i didnt want to post too much code, but i have another 2 structures, each is an array of another

Answer (score 1):

Heard of the [Rule of Three](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4172722/what-is-the-rule-of-three)?

It looks like you should take advantage of the object oriented part of C++ and make `tcFrame` a full fledged object (hint `class`). After this you can create appropriate constructors and destructors, along with a copy constructor and a overloaded copy assignment.

...But why are you using dynamic memory anyways? C++ provides `std::vector` dynamic arrays with no headache.

Answer (score 0):

You have to allocate memory for `Frame2.Stimulus` and copy the contents of `Frame1.Stimulus` to it.

```
Frame2.Stimulus = new tcFrameStimulus[Frame1.Config.Length];
Frame2.Stimulus[0] = Frame1.Stimulus[0];
Frame2.Stimulus[1] = Frame1.Stimulus[1];
Frame2.Stimulus[2] = Frame1.Stimulus[2];
Frame2.Stimulus[3] = Frame1.Stimulus[3];
```

Otherwise, `Frame2` and `Frame1` point to the same memory. If you modify one, it will affect the other.

Since you are going to use c++, it will be a lot better to use the containers from the standard library, such as `std::vector`, `std::array`. Otherwise, you will be dealing with memory related problems.

For your case, you can use:

```
struct tcFrame 
{
   tcFrameConfig      Config;
   std::vector<tcFrameStimulus> Stimulus;
};
```

That way, you can just use:

```
Frame2 = Frame1;
```

without worrying about memory allocation, memory deallocation, assignment of data from one list to another, etc.

Comment: i tried
struct tcFrame 
{
   tcFrameConfig      Config;
   std::vector<tcFrameStimulus> Stimulus;
};
it says the struct has no member names Stimulus

Comment: If you can posted an update, with the updated code and copy and paste the compiler error message, it will be helpful.

Comment: I think you should leave your original code. Add the new code and the compiler error messages at the end of the post.

Comment: like that? its actually my 1st post in stackoverflow :s

Comment: Sounds like you forgot to `#include <vector>` in your code.

Comment: yeah, sorry, that was it, will implement, and make the changes in the rest of the code, thanks for your attention.